# What does LINQ return when the results are empty

Tags: c#, linq

I have a question about LINQ query. Normally a query returns a `IEnumerable<T>` type. If the return is empty, not sure if it is null or not. I am not sure if the following `ToList()` will throw an exception or just a empty `List<string>` if nothing found in `IEnumerable` result?

```
   List<string> list = {"a"};
   // is the result null or something else?
   IEnumerable<string> ilist = from x in list where x == "ABC" select x;
   // Or directly to a list, exception thrown?
   List<string> list1 = (from x in list where x == "ABC" select x).ToList();
```

I know it is a very simple question, but I don't have VS available for the time being.

Comment: I guess the result is Enumerable.Empty?

Answer (score 665, accepted):

It will return an empty enumerable. It won't be null. You can sleep sound  :)

Comment: Just FYI: You made it to r/ProgrammerHumor 

Comment: Link or it didnt happen :D

Comment: Here you go :) https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/pv09ys/googled_this_at_3_am_last_night_the_answer/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 51):

You can also check the `.Any()` method:

```
if (!YourResult.Any())
```

Just a note that `.Any` will still retrieve the records from the database; doing a `.FirstOrDefault()/.Where()` will be just as much overhead but you would then be able to catch the object(s) returned from the query

Comment: Where does the question mention a database?

Comment: You'll have to ask the one who edited, I didn't mention any DB :)

Comment: Point editor is making is sound, though, DB or not.  I believe they are saying `.Any()` is just going to tell you if you have any matching records, at all, where doing an actual query to find a specific value might be null when `.Any()` is not.

Comment: The edit might actually be wrong. If using linq to entities, the db might shortcut this and no data at all is being sent to the client except a true or false

Answer (score 25):

```
var lst = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var ans = lst.Where( i => i > 3 );

(ans == null).Dump();  // False
(ans.Count() == 0 ).Dump();  // True
```

(Dump is from [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/))

Comment: Exactly! You get a better indication of the findings

Comment: TIL `Count()` is also a method, not just the property

Comment: Shouldn't you use .Any() because count will enumerate through all items?

Answer (score 19):

.ToList returns an empty list. (same as `new List<T>()` );

Answer (score 9):

In Linq-to-SQL if you try to get the first element on a query with no results you will get `sequence contains no elements` error. I can assure you that the mentioned error is not equal to `object reference not set to an instance of an object`. 
in conclusion no, it won't return null since null can't say `sequence contains no elements` it will always say `object reference not set to an instance of an object` ;)

Comment: Oh,  your explanation helps further understanding. Thank you !

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Answer (score 8):

It won't throw exception, you'll get an empty list.

Comment: What is the correct way to throw exceptions in case of getting null? Do we have to check it after the query with if-else statements?

Comment: @SBU you can check it with Any() and throw an exception yourself:
var result = source.Where(s=>s.Name == "SBU");
if(!result.Any())
  throw new Exception("Result Is empty");

Answer (score 8):

Other posts here have made it clear that the result is an "empty" `IQueryable`, which `ToList()` will correctly change to be an empty list etc.

Do be careful with some of the operators, as they will throw if you send them an empty enumerable.  This can happen when you chain them together.

Comment: "Do be careful with some of the operators, as they will throw if you send them an empty enumerable. This can happen when you chain them together." -- This is what got me.  I had a null returned value that I then fed into another query.  This caused the second query to throw no matter what I cast it to because there was no value being fed into the second query.