# If a linq query returns empty does it return null?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have the following linq query:

```
     vm.logs = (from l in db.ActivityLogs
                   orderby l.Time
                   select l).Take(2);
```

If the db table is empty will this return null?

If not how can I detect if a query did return any information?

Comment: OP -- Think it's worth flagging your question [a dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191919/what-does-linq-return-when-the-results-are-empty), or did you think it was different enough in some way to keep it around?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will return an `IEnumerable<ActivityLog>` with no elements.

To check if there are any elements, use the `Any()` method:

```
if(!logs.Any())
{
   Console.WriteLine("No elements found.");
}
```

Also note that as you've written it, `vm.logs` will be *lazily evaluated*, that is, it won't be fetched from the database until it is used. If you first do a `.Any()` and then later access the contents of the query, there will be *two queries* executed in the database. To avoid that, materialize (force the query to execute) by adding a `ToList()` to the query:

```
 vm.logs = (from l in db.ActivityLogs
               orderby l.Time
               select l).Take(2).ToList();
```

Comment: Take care here, if the take two returns nothing;
`select l).Take(2).ToList();`
It will be null instead of empty set, so this will crash.

Comment: @Ostmeistro No, `Take(2)` returns an empty set if there are no elements. Try e.g. `Enumerable.Empty<int>().Take(2)` - it will return an empty `IEnumerable<int>`.