# Login Form not Authenticating credentials

Tags: c#, winforms

Cant Seem to find the bug, the query always returns null result, even if the login and password is wrong.
I have tried debugging through VS, But there seems to be problem with the query.

```
E_MedicalDataContext EM = new E_MedicalDataContext();
        var result = from u in EM.users
                     where u.Username == Login_UN.Text && u.Password == Login_P.Text
                     select u;
        if(result!=null)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Checkout D = new Checkout();
            D.ShowDialog();
        }
       else
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Login Credentials Wrong")
        }
```

Comment: Why would you expect the query to return null? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191919/what-does-linq-return-when-the-results-are-empty

Comment: use `var result = (from ... ).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev It worked out...!