# does c# null-conditional operator works with linq methods

Tags: c#, linq, operator-keyword

I am trying to use elvis operator to achieve something like this

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "str1", "str2", "str3"};

string searchkey = "str4"; // this does not exist in the list so will use elvis operator before picking the first from the resulting sequence.

var result = list.where(s=>(s.Contains(searchkey)))?.First();
```

I expect result to be null but the code actually throws an exception.

Comment: 1. That's not the [Elvis Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator), 2. `Where` should be capitalized, 3. [`Where` will never return `null`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191919/what-does-linq-return-when-the-results-are-empty)

Comment: What is the _actual_ code and error message?

Comment: Also, is your actual requirement "return the item if it's in the list, otherwise return the first item in the list"?

Comment: You can use .FirstorDefault() instead

Comment: This is called the `Null Conditional Operator`, not the Elvis operator, as D Stanley mentioned: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx

Comment: A year or two back, I saw a talk by a MS C#6 evangelist who called null-conditional the Elvis operator. I'm not mistaken; the talk was about the new features in C#6. I'd never heard the term, and I learned the ternary `?:` when I started learning C in 1995. So it's quite possible that OP heard "Elvis Operator" from somebody you'd think would know what he was talking about.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that

```
list.Where(s=>(s.Contains(searchkey)))
```

does not return `null`; it returns an empty sequence, which is not the same thing.

If you would like to get a `null` when the sequence of objects is empty, use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var result = list.FirstOrDefault(s=>(s.Contains(searchkey)));
```

**Note:** C#'s version of "Elvis Operator" is `||`, not `?.`. The operator in your code is called *null conditional operator*.

Comment: '||' is logical or; '?.' is indeed the elvis operator

Answer (score 0):

Because `Where` operator returns anything to enumerate and `First()` cannot be evaluated. You may use `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: "`Where` operator returns `null`" [no it doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191919/what-does-linq-return-when-the-results-are-empty)...

Comment: Ok it doesn't return null, but returns no element to iterate. I will edit. By the way, thank you for heads up.