# Asp .Net MVC, why my viewbag always not null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have assigned some data from database table into my viewbag in controller. Since there is no containing data, my viewbag returns true. Why is this happened?

**Controller**

```
//bear in mind that there is no status == 1, all were status == 0
Viewbag.itemlist = db.Furnitures.Where(x => x.Status == 1).ToList();
```

**View**

```
@if(Viewbag.itemlist != null)
{
   //The string is displayed even tho it does not contain any data
   <p>I appear</p>
}
```

Comment: `ToList()` never returns `null`. It returns an empty list.

Comment: Because your query cannot return `null` - its returns an empty collection

Comment: how do i check whether it is empty collection or not?

Comment: How do you check a list is empty?

Comment: I usually do `== null`

Comment: Having an empty list is different from not having a list.

Comment: If i may ask, what are the syntax to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does LINQ return when the results are empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1191919/11683) and [Check if list is empty in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18867180/11683)

Comment: `@if(Viewbag.itemlist.Any())` or `@if(Viewbag.itemlist.Count > 0)`

Comment: You can just count how many items are in the list to know if it's empty. To make a real-world analogy: How do you know if your shopping bag is empty? You'd count the items in it, of course. And an empty shopping bag is different from not actually having a bag at all (this scenario would be the equivalent of null in the code)

Comment: Thank you @StephenMuecke for the straightforward answers. Unfortunately `@if(Viewbag.itemlist.Any())` does not work, have an error says `does not contain a definition for 'Any''` but the other solution (Count>0) works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check if a List is empty, try this:

```
@if( ((List<Furnitures>) Viewbag.itemlist).Count > 0)
{
    //The string is displayed even tho it does not contain any data
    <p>I appear</p>
}
```

or

```
@if( ((List<Furnitures>) Viewbag.itemlist).Any())
{
    //The string is displayed even tho it does not contain any data
    <p>I appear</p>
}
```

## Update:

As pointed out by  @learnprogramming, the second solution doesn't work.
.Any() doesn't operate on a List, it operates on an IEnumerable.

To make it works you need to add

```
@using System.Linq
```

to the top of your view file. Thanks to @ColinM for the tip.

## Update 2

Another tip from @Colin.
MVC has full support for model binding between Controllers and Views.

It's way better to pass data with model binding instead of ViewBag.
In your ActionResult you should do this:

```
var furnituresList = db.Furnitures.Where(x => x.Status == 1).ToList();
return View(furnituresList);
```

Then in your view put this on top (after the @using directives):

```
@model List<Furnitures>
```

And then check with this:

```
@if(Model.Count > 0)
{
    //The string is displayed even tho it does not contain any data
    <p>I appear</p>
}
```

Comment: the second solution does not work though...error saying `does not contain a definition for 'Any''`...the other solution work fine

Comment: The second solution actually will work if you add `@using System.Linq` to the top of your view file. `Any()` is an extension method of `IEnumerable<T>` which `List<T>` implements.

Comment: Another recommendation would be to provide an option in your answer for Model binding, rather than using `ViewBag` and casting. What if `itemList` isn't a `List<Furnitures>` due to developer error at some point ;-)